# While deploying stack encountered ' Unsupported ActionTypeId' error

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

When I create cloudformation stack for codepipeline, it fails and the error message is "Encountered unsupported property ActionTypeId".

Template is:

```
    AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Model and provision AWS CodePipeline and AWS CodeBuild

Parameters:
  CodePipelineSourceBucketName:
    Type: String
    Description: Bucket to store source code
    Default: covid19-codepipeline-source

  CodePipelineSourceObjectKey:
    Type: String
    Description: Object key of zip file uploaded to source bucket
    Default: source.zip 

  CodePipelineArtifactStoreBucketName:
    Type: String
    Description: Bucket to store artifacts created by codepipeline
    Default: covid19-codepipeline-artifacts

  CloudTrailLogsBucketName:
    Type: String
    Description: Bucket to store cloudtrail logs
    Default: covid19-cloudtrail-logs

Resources:
  # CodePipeline
  DeployPipelineForGlueWorkflow: 
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties: 
      Name: !Sub DeployPipelineForGlueWorkflow-${AWS::StackName}
      RoleArn: !GetAtt CodePipelineRole.Arn
      ArtifactStore: 
        Type: S3
        Location: !Ref CodePipelineArtifactStoreBucket
      Stages: 
      - 
        Name: Source
        Actions: 
        - 
          Name: SourceAction
          ActionTypeId: 
            Category: Source
            Owner: AWS
            Version: "1"
            Provider: S3
          OutputArtifacts: 
            - Name: SourceOutput
          Configuration: 
            S3Bucket: !Ref CodePipelineSourceBucket
            S3ObjectKey: !Ref CodePipelineSourceObjectKey 
            PollForSourceChanges: false
          RunOrder: 1
      -
```

I checked the indentation as well but still facing same issue.

Comment: Do you have the rest of the template, or are you confident that the issue originates from what you've posted?

Comment: yess the stack is stuck at the early stages

Comment: I don't think the error originates here.

Comment: Thanks I was able to resolve.

Comment: Yes answers were helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but to accept you have to click a "tick" symbol under upvote/downvote buttons of the answer.